# SFML реализация коллизии

Tags: c++, sfml, коллизии

Всем добрый день!

Решил немного попрактиковаться в ООП в C++. Решил написать небольшую игру с помощью библиотеки SFML. Но возникла проблема с реализацией коллизии (гг проходит сквозь статичные объекты). Может кто помочь с её реализацией?

[image: страус проходит сквозь объекты]

Код программы:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

#include "LifeBar.h"

using namespace sf;
using namespace std;
RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(640, 480), "Straus"); //окно

class Obj {
public:
    virtual void draw() = 0;
};

class Persona_5 :public Obj {
private:
    Texture Pesn_Tex;
    Sprite Pesn_Spr;
    Clock Pesn_Clock;
    float time;
    float CurrentFrame;
public:
    //Конструктор объекта
    Persona_5(string File_Path);
    void Move_From_KeyBoard();
    void draw();
};

class Static_obj : public Obj {
private:
    Texture obj_Tex;
    Sprite obj_Spr;
public:
    Static_obj(string File_Path, int x, int y, int l, int t, int w, int h);
    void draw();
};

void Static_obj::draw() { // отрисовка статических объектов
    //window.clear();
    window.draw(obj_Spr);
}

Static_obj::Static_obj(string File_Path, int x, int y, int l, int t, int w, int h) { 
    obj_Tex.loadFromFile(File_Path);
    obj_Spr.setTexture(obj_Tex);
    obj_Spr.setTextureRect(IntRect(l, t, w, h));
    obj_Spr.setPosition(x, y);
}

void Persona_5::draw() { //отрисовка гг
    //window.clear();
    Move_From_KeyBoard();
    window.draw(Pesn_Spr);
}


Persona_5::Persona_5(string File_Path) {
    Pesn_Tex.loadFromFile(File_Path);
    Pesn_Spr.setTexture(Pesn_Tex);
    Pesn_Spr.setTextureRect(IntRect(0, 192, 48, 48));
    Pesn_Spr.setPosition(50, 50);
    time = 0;
    CurrentFrame = 0;
    window.clear();
    window.draw(Pesn_Spr);
    window.display();
}

void Persona_5::Move_From_KeyBoard() { //управление
    time = Pesn_Clock.getElapsedTime().asMicroseconds();
    time = time / 800;
    Pesn_Clock.restart();
    if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::W)) {
        CurrentFrame += 0.005 * time;
        if (CurrentFrame > 3) CurrentFrame -= 3;
        Pesn_Spr.move(0, 0.1 * time);
        Pesn_Spr.setTextureRect(IntRect(48 * int(CurrentFrame), 0, 48, 48));
    }
    else if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::S)) {
        CurrentFrame += 0.005 * time;
        if (CurrentFrame > 3) CurrentFrame -= 3;
        Pesn_Spr.move(0, -0.1 * time);
        Pesn_Spr.setTextureRect(IntRect(48 * int(CurrentFrame), 144, 48, 48));
    }
    else if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::A)) {
        CurrentFrame += 0.005 * time;
        if (CurrentFrame > 3) CurrentFrame -= 3;
        Pesn_Spr.move(-0.1 * time, 0);
        Pesn_Spr.setTextureRect(IntRect(48 * int(CurrentFrame), 48, 48, 48));
    }
    else if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::D)) {
        CurrentFrame += 0.005 * time;
        if (CurrentFrame > 3) CurrentFrame -= 3;
        Pesn_Spr.move(0.1 * time, 0);
        Pesn_Spr.setTextureRect(IntRect(48 * int(CurrentFrame), 48 * 2, 48, 48));
    }
    else {
        return;
    }

    //window.clear();
    //window.draw(Pesn_Spr);
    //window.display();
}


int main()
{
    Persona_5 My_Obj("images/straus.png");
    Static_obj mo("images/forest.png", 100, 100, 290, 193, 90, 90); //1 2 - положение 3 4 - объект 5 6 - размер 

    LifeBar lifeBarPlayer;//экземпляр класса полоски здоровья

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        lifeBarPlayer.update(100);//сюда передаем значение, которое надо нарисовать. Можно передать здоровья игрока тогда будет lifeBarPlayer.update(player.getHealth()); 
        window.clear();
        lifeBarPlayer.draw(window);//рисуем полоску здоровья
        My_Obj.draw();
        mo.draw();
        window.display();

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: SMFL либа для рисунков и прочего системного апи, никаких проверок пересечения в ней нет и не должно быть. Box2D может помочь.

Answer (score 0):

- obj1 - объект который пересечётся.
- obj2 - объект с которым пересечётся.

```
obj1.getGlobalBounds().intersects(obj2.getGlobalBounds());
```

Простейший вариант.